# Existence of Expectation of Product of Two Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In the theorem's proof (See screenshot link; StackExchange does not yet allow me to directly insert images), the author uses the linearity of expectation. However, linearity of expectation requires that each individual expectation being summed is finite. How do we know that E(XY) is finite given only that both variances are finite? Thank you!

**Proof**

[image]

Comment: Apply Holder's/Cauchy Schwarz inequality.

Comment: Notice that in the statement of the Theorem, it is assumed that $X$ and $Y$ have finite variances. That implies that $E[X^2]$ and $E[Y^2]$ are finite. This also implies the integrability of $XY$ by [Cauchy-Schwatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy–Schwarz_inequality#L2) inequality.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Thank you for your help. Does the implication that E[X^{2}] and E[Y^{2}] are finite come from the alternate method for calculating the variance: Var(X)=E(X^{2}) - [E(X)]^{2}? I apologize if the notation is hard to understand; I am new to these types of posts.

Comment: For the variance to exists, the random variables need to be square integrable.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an elementary proof. Use the inequality
$$(X+Y)^2\le 2(X^2+Y^2)$$
to see that $E(X+Y)^2$ is finite whenever $X$ and $Y$ have finite variances. Next, the identity
$$2XY = (X+Y)^2 -X^2 -Y^2$$
implies that $XY$ has finite expectation.

Answer (score 1):

Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$
E\left[|XY|\right]\le\sqrt{E[X^2]\cdot E[Y^2]}.
$$